# cocos2d ccDrawSolidPoly in a CCRenderTexture sometimes creates a blank asset (possible race condition)

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a function intended to create a trapezoidal polygon `CCSprite`. 99% of the time, the function works fine. The other 1%, it creates a completely blank sprite (though, of the correct dimensions). Here's my function:

```
- (CCRenderTexture*)createPolygon {
  CGFloat bottom = [self bottomCrop];
  CGFloat top = self.contentSize.height - [self topCrop];
  CGFloat constrict = PERSPECTIVE_CONSTRICT_PX_FOR_HEIGHT(top);

  CCRenderTexture * rt = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:self.contentSize.width
                                                          height:self.contentSize.height];
  [rt begin];

  CGPoint pts[] = { ccp(0,bottom),
    ccp(constrict,top),
    ccp(self.contentSize.width-constrict,top),
    ccp(self.contentSize.width,bottom) };
  ccDrawSolidPoly(pts, 4, ccc4FFromccc3B(self.backgroundColor));

  [rt end];
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
  [rt saveToFile:@"terrain.jpg"];
#endif
  return rt;
}
```

As you can see, I'm saving the RenderTexture to a file so that I can compare good vs. bad output. As I said above, the dimensions of the files are the same, but in the edge case the polygon is simply missing from the output.

I'm guessing I have some sort of race condition with another function (perhaps `ccDrawSolidRect` is drawing into the wrong context...?), but I have no idea where it might be. Is there any way I can protect against this?

**edit** FWIW, I'm positive that `self.backgroundColor` is not white/transparent, so that should not be the problem. Similarly, I'm sure that `bottom` and `top` are non-zero. These values are all coded as switch statements, based upon some configurations.

Comment: Race condition can't be it, cocos2d isn't multithreaded and if you were to run this on a separate thread it wouldn't work (most likely crash) because all cocos2d render methods expect to run on the main thread where the OpenGL context is.

Comment: Try using saveToFile:format: and use PNG as format because saving (and loading) a JPG is particularly slow in cocos2d.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D to be clear, the saving part is just a debug feature to help me compare outputs. It has nothing to do with the actual execution of the application (e.g., the problem predates the addition of that line).